# Block validation failed - save content vs post body content

Tags: block-editor

This issue has come back to haunt me again and this time Tom, I look forward to learning from this is so I can **trueeely** get it, and solve my own block violations. I just need a little on the learning curve "on what to look for".

From wp-admin the error I get in the console when the post loads...

```html
Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-blachawk-hc-alert-block hc-alert-block-group has-bg-color-wheat01 has-txt-color-black" style="background-color:#f1dcaa;color:black"><div class="wp-block-blachawk-hc-alert-block has-icon-<div class=&quot;wp-block-blachawk-hc-alert-block has-icon-info has-icon-color-blackn75&quot;&gt;</div&gt;<div class=&quot;innerContent&quot;&gt;

</div&gt; has-icon-color-<div"></div><div class="innerContent"></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-blachawk-hc-alert-block hc-alert-block-group has-bg-color-wheat01 has-txt-color-black" style="background-color:#f1dcaa;color:black"><div class="wp-block-blachawk-hc-alert-block has-icon-info has-icon-color-blackn75"></div><div class="innerContent">

</div></div>
```

So obviously there is a mismatch. I can see from above that `has-icon-<div class=&quot;wp-bl...` is wrong, and wondering why in the world does wordpress have issues with....

```js
    const iconProps = useBlockProps({
        className: `has-icon-${bgIcon} has-icon-color-${bgIconColor}`,
    });
```

This is a simple message block plugin I created from scratch with create block. Here are the goods:

`block.json`

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "blachawk/hc-alert-block",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "HC Alert Block Info Wheat",
    "category": "text",
    "description": "A custom text block available in multiple color sets",
    "keywords": ["nffa", "hc", "help", "text", "variations", "item"],
    "supports": {
        "html": false,
        "color": {
            "background": true,
            "text": true
        }
    },
    "textdomain": "_hcab",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css",
    "attributes": {
        "colorBgDefault": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "wheat01"
        },
        "colorBgChange": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "#f1dcaa"
        },
        "colorTxtDefault": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "black"
        },
        "colorTxtChange": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "black"
        },
        "bgIcon": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div",
            "attribute": "class",
            "default": "info"
        },
        "bgIconColor": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "html",
            "selector": "div",
            "attribute": "class",
            "default": "blackn75"
        },
        "_cover": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ""
        }
    },
    "example": {
        "attributes": {
            "_cover": "https://placehold.co/600x401/000000/FFF"
        }
    }
}
```

`edit.js`

```js
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

import {
    useBlockProps,
    BlockControls,
    InnerBlocks,
    useInnerBlocksProps,
    InspectorControls,
    PanelColorSettings,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const {
        colorBgDefault,
        colorBgChange,
        colorTxtDefault,
        colorTxtChange,
        bgIcon,
        bgIconColor,
        _cover,
    } = attributes;

    //PREVIEW PANAL BYPASS
    if (attributes._cover) {
        return <img src={attributes._cover} alt="" />;
    }

    //PARENT CONTAINER ATTRIBUTES
    const parentProps = useBlockProps({
        className: `hc-alert-block-group has-bg-color-${colorBgDefault} has-txt-color-${colorTxtDefault}`,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: colorBgChange,
            color: colorTxtChange,
        },
    });

    //ICON ATTRIBUTES
    const iconProps = useBlockProps({
        className: `has-icon-${bgIcon} has-icon-color-${bgIconColor}`,
    });

    //ENABLED INNER BLOCKS | RENDER APPENDER
    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps({
        allowedBlocks: ['nffa-blocks-v/text-block-item'],
        renderAppender: InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender,
    });

    //COLOR CHANGE OPTIONS FROM THE SIDEBAR
    const onColorBgChange = (newColorBg) => {
        setAttributes({ colorBgChange: newColorBg });
    };

    const onColorTxtChange = (newColorTxt) => {
        setAttributes({ colorTxtChange: newColorTxt });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelColorSettings
                    title={__('Color Settings', '_hcab')}
                    icon="admin-appearance"
                    initialOpen
                    colorSettings={[
                        {
                            value: colorBgChange,
                            onChange: onColorBgChange,
                            label: __('Background Color', '_hcab'),
                        },
                        {
                            value: colorTxtChange,
                            onChange: onColorTxtChange,
                            label: __('Text Color', '_hcab'),
                        },
                    ]}
                />
            </InspectorControls>

            <div {...parentProps}>
                <div {...iconProps} />
                <div {...innerBlocksProps} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

`save.js`

```js
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const {
        colorBgDefault,
        colorBgChange,
        colorTxtDefault,
        colorTxtChange,
        bgIcon,
        bgIconColor,
        _cover,
    } = attributes;

    //PARENT CONTAINER ATTRIBUTES
    const parentProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: `hc-alert-block-group has-bg-color-${colorBgDefault} has-txt-color-${colorTxtDefault}`,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: colorBgChange,
            color: colorTxtChange,
        },
    });

    //ICON ATTRIBUTES
    const iconProps = useBlockProps.save({
        className: `has-icon-${bgIcon} has-icon-color-${bgIconColor}`,
    });

    return (
        <div {...parentProps}>
            <div {...iconProps} />
            <div className="innerContent">
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and within my `/src` directory, I have a sub block in a folder called `hc-alert-block-item`

`edit.js`

```js
import { useBlockProps, useInnerBlocksProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
// import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default function Edit({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps(blockProps);

    return (
        <>
            <div {...innerBlocksProps} />
        </>
    );
}
```

`save.js`

```js
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Save() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <InnerBlocks.Content />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Many many thanks on any "ideas" to consider in solving this violation. Again, I don't know what is off...

Comment: If the **source** of an attribute in your block is an HTML attribute like `class`, then the `source` should be `attribute`, [as documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#value-source). But your `bgIcon` and `bgIconColor` attributes are using `"source": "html"`, which is incorrect, hence it resulted in that block validation error.

Comment: That was definitely a step in the right direction. I will forever remember this! I see how I have to re-build some of my logic because source:attribute for class, will always get "all the class names" on that attribute...not just the one I need.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So you might instead want to use an input like a checkbox, for those 2 attributes, then use the [`classnames` package](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to conditionally add those classes, depending on the input values. [Something like this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/9fd9dadde5cd68832b1364d6810a7b009b2938d9/packages/block-library/src/paragraph/save.js#L14-L20) in the core paragraph block.

Comment: I'm forever grateful for this lesson. Thank you!